# DuplicateTable error on heroku run rake db:migrate, what is the next step to resolve this issue?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku-postgres

Command on terminal:
 `$ heroku run rake db:migrate`

Error on terminal :

```
PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "users" already exists
: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" serial primary key, "email" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "encrypted_password" character varying(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "reset_password_token" character varying(255), "reset_password_sent_at" timestamp, "remember_created_at" timestamp, "sign_in_count" integer DEFAULT 0, "current_sign_in_at" timestamp, "last_sign_in_at" timestamp, "current_sign_in_ip" character varying(255), "last_sign_in_ip" character varying(255)) /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:128:in `async_exec'
```

Under the db/migrate folder there are 2 files as given below:

20140503215545_devise_create_users.rb

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
  end
end
```

20140503215546_add_devise_to_users.rb

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      # Uncomment below if timestamps were not included in your original model.
      # t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

I am quite new in rails. Suggest me ways to run this migration successfully.

Answer (score 3):

They are both effectively duplicates. The 2nd migration is in the older migration API (using `self.up` and `self.down`) and the 1st migration is using the newer migration API (just a `change` instance method).

I'd delete the 2nd migration, migrate locally, and push to heroku and try again.

Comment: I have tried deleting the 2nd migration and tried but, same error persists. Then I did a `$heroku run rake db:schema:load`, now it is working.